# Zumero Xamarin Won't Compile

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin, zumero

I am trying to use the Zumero Xamarin component, but I get a compiler error.

```
The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
```

I included the component to my project and added the following code.

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

And

```
        string personalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string dbName = "pitches.db";
        string dbPath = Path.Combine ( personalFolder, dbName);
        var conn = new  SQLiteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath); 
        conn.Open (); 
        conn.ZumeroRegister();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Following the same steps, this problem happens for me as well.
2. If I then add a reference to System.Data, the error goes away and the code compiles.  Looking at your screenshot, it appears that you do not have a reference to System.Data.  Under the Project menu, choose Edit References, make sure the All tab is open, and then put a checkmark next to System.Data.
3. I am using the recently-released Xamarin.iOS 6.4.  I don't remember needing to do this step before, which suggests that perhaps previous versions of Xamarin.iOS included the reference to System.Data by default.  I've got a little uncertainty here yet that needs to be eliminated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Eric!  Worked perfectly!  You are the best!